How does React determine which state to apply when children are conditionally rendered?
React maintains its states by storing the order of useState calls and fill in the states with that order during the next re-rendering.
But when there is a conditional re-rendering, like having a boolean flag to control whether a child will be shown or not, this order is broken.
import { useState } from 'react';

const Counter = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click to increment: {count}
      </button>
  );
};

const CounterGroup = ({ visible }) => {
  // visible controls whether the first counter is displayed
  return (
      <div>
        { visible && <Counter/> }
        <Counter/>
      </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(true);

  return (
      <div>
        <CounterGroup visible={ visible }/>
        <p>
          <button onClick={ () => setVisible(!visible) }>
            Toggle Counter
          </button>
        </p>
      </div>
  );
};

export default App;

In this example, when rendering App, 3 states are used: one visible and two count's. But when visible is set to false, there are only one visible and one count state to fill in. How does React know which count is the one to preserve (which is the second apparently)?

If you don't render something it's not just set to invisible but kept around in memory for potential later use. It's not "hidden" and React isn't "skipping" that child's hook. If it's not rendered the component is unmounted and disposed of. It doesn't exist in React's field of view, left to be cleaned up by JS garbage collector. Like deleting an object property. It's lost, and React creates a brand new Child component when you set visible back to true, one that's completely separate and unrelated to that first child. They have no connection.

@Jayce444 Does code like <Child /> immediately executes function Child or just stores the data like in xml and waits for React to render them together?

@OrthoPole react causes rendering to occur when the state value changes. render means redrawing the return part of the jsx. as the visible state changes, the  is rendered and the state value in the child is initialized. it has nothing to do with visible. if you move the state in the child to the parent and pass it to the child as a props, you can have a complete counter value.

You think the React engineers hadn't considered to write the React library to know what is mounted and clean up resources it uses to track all the hooks and state? Or is this what your question is really about, how React is implemented?

@DrewReese Yeah, I'm asking how React is implemented actually. I'm trying to understand the principle of React hooks.

@DrewReese Sorry about unclarity of my words. I've added a summary to fix this.


How does React do this? The conditional means that the child component
may not be being rendered, so the global list of use state calls
within a render is inconsistent, which seems to violate the hook
rules. ... What’s the internal logic react uses?

Note: The following post has been made by referring the documentation here Preserving and Resetting State. Please note that it found to me very very helpful.
The Render Tree is the backbone for this.
As we know, a React App consists of components. And the components can contain components within it.
This relationship of the components in an App can be modelled to a Tree. A Render Tree is the same Tree model, but it is with respect to a particular render pass of the App. We also know the Render Tree may differ in render when the JSX returns conditionally. We will address conditional rendering separately during our discussions.
Now let us start with a very simple App, shown below.
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Component />
      <br />
      <Component />
    </div>
  );
}

function Component() {
  return 'I am Component';
}

Let us draw below the Render Tree of the App.
The Render Tree
// App
//    Component
//    Component

React has an addressing mechanism for each node in the tree. It is based on the position of the components in the container of the JSX. This is the default addressing mechanism React uses. Now let us write the address of each node as per this mechanism.
The Render Tree with node address
//  App - root component
//    Component - the first child component in the container div
//    Component - the second child component in the container div

Now let us add some states into our component. Please note that the states have initial values through the props initialValue.
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Component initialValue={1} />
      <br />
      <Component initialValue={2} />
    </div>
  );
}

function Component({ initialValue }) {
  const [someState, setSomeState] = useState(initialValue);
  return 'I am Component with the state someState and the value : ' + someState;
}

Now let us see how React identifies the states with respect to its components.
React uses the Render Tree and its node addresses for this and it does the process as below.
The process to Identify the states
// Upon the initial render, the Render Tree will be available.
// React traverses through the Render Tree.
// It starts with the root component.
// It finds no state in it, as per this example.
// Then it takes the first child component in the container div.
// It finds a state in it.
// It records it as this:
//   This state belongs to the component under the context, it means
//   the state belongs to the first child in the container div.
// It finds no more state in the same component.
// Therefore it takes the second child component.
// It finds a state in it.
// It records as this:
//    This state belongs to the second child in the container div.
// If finds no more child components in the App, therefore it ends the 
// process.

Note:
If any of the child component has components within it, then it would go into it, and identify the
states within it in the same way we discussed above. And this process will continue recursively since
Render Tree is a Tree structure.
Now the above process has resulted in a record as below
The record of States identified with its components
// someState with value 1 belongs to the first child component in the 
// container

// someState with value 2 belongs to the second child component in the 
// container

By the way, the states in a component live outside of the component. It lives with React.
Therefore identifying the states with respect to its components is a necessary process. That is what we have seen above.
Now let us see what happens on the first re-render. Although this app does not trigger a state change and therefore no chance to re-render, we can see assume the JSX if there is re-render. Such state changes are deliberately avoided from this initial discussion, we shall see it in action when we see conditional rendering subsequently.
This example App will produce the same Render Tree again on re-rendering.
The Render Tree on the first re-render
//  App - root component
//    Component - the first child component in the container div
//    Component - the second child component in the container div

And now the states will be matched with the respective components in the latest Render Tree. The record of the states in the initial render will be referenced here.
// As per the record, someState with value 1 belongs to the first child 
// component in the container.

// Yes, someState with value 1 will again be associated with the same 
// component since the first child component in the container in the new 
// render still matches with the state's record.

// As per the record, someState with value 2 belongs to the second child 
// component in the container.

// Yes, someState with value 2 will again be associated with the same 
// component since the second child component in the container in the new 
// render still matches with the state's record.

This process will continue on each render.
Now the state retention rule is this :
Between two renders - the current and the just previous one, the states will be retained as long as the same components are rendered at the same position in the Render Tree.
Now we shall take the cases of conditional rendering.
To keep the size of this post manageable, this is being stopped here. To resume reading, please see the other post titled "Conditional rendering".

Conditional rendering shall be posted by tomorrow. This is due to the shortage of time. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Why don't you merge all 4 parts of your answer into one?

Hi Greetings, As you know, splits will reduce the scrolling while writing, also writing  in this interface is not as easy as writing in a plain editor. Still I will do so as per your request. Let me finish and post the 4th part as well today. Merging shall be done in next week by Wed.

This is a really long and detailed answer. I think you may post it in a blog and put a link here. Anyway, really appreciate your answer.

Thank you for your appreciation and advice. I shall try so. Best wishes to you.

Posting multiple answers to a single question is generally discouraged unless they're truly distinct solutions. Multi-part answers like this aren't really allowed. But thanks for the explanation, you've really cleared things up! I think one thing I'd been forgetting is that I'd been thinking about purely functional components as if they were just function calls, but of course that's wrong, they de-sugar into calls to React.createElement or _jsx, so React can use that to know where to create the new node in the Render tree, rather than blindly trying to figure it out from the return values.

I made the multiple posts just because of the inconvenience in writing with this interface, We hardly get a relatively small window to write. However, I fully agree with you, it is incorrect to do, since it is just the same answer. I shall correct it soon. Thank you for the caution and for the appreciation. The author of this question had also raised this concern. @JeremyBanks

Hi OrthoPole, Thank you for the bounty granted.

The bounty was from me, actually, but you’re welcome.  I appreciate you sharing this understanding.

I am really sorry, It is my mistake. Thank you for the bounty as well as for the appreciation. @JeremyBanks

The following post has reference to the first two parts of the 4-part answer.
Answer part 3 of 4
Controlling Conditional rendering:
In the previous post, we have very closely seen how does the state retention rule work. Let us recall the same - The same component in the same position retains the state.
The two conditional rendering examples we have seen in the previous post worked against our expectation.
We expected the below output.
// The first code should show the state values in the order 
// 1,2,1,2,1,2... on load and on each button click respectively.

    
// The second code should show the state values in the order 
// 2,1,2,1,2,1... on load and on each button click respectively.

However, it resulted in the below undesired output.
// The first code always shows the state value 1.
    
// The second code always shows the state value 2.

Now in this post, we shall see how to control the default state retention behaviour and achieve the expected results.
We have below two options:
a. Reserve the component positions permanently in the Render Tree.
b. Opt for name based addressing mechanism which will prevail over the default position based addressing.
We shall start with the first option.
Reserve the component positions permanently in the Render Tree.
Let us see the following code, which is a modified version of the first code in the previous post.
first code modified
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [toggleShow, setToggleShow] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      {!toggleShow ? (
        <Component initialValue={1} title="first ternary" />
      ) : null}
      {toggleShow ? (
        <Component initialValue={2} title="second ternary" />
      ) : null}
      <br />
      <button onClick={() => setToggleShow(!toggleShow)}>
        Click to re-render
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

function Component({ initialValue, title }) {
  const [someState, setSomeState] = useState(initialValue);

  return `I am the Component in the ${title} operator with the state someState and the value ${someState}`;
}

Test runs
Browser display on its first render / loading the App

Browser display on the second render / on the first click of the button

Observations:
The screenshots above show that the modified code has resulted in the expected results.
We shall now see the modification is detail below.
{!toggleShow ? (
<Component initialValue={1} title="first ternary" />
) : null}

{toggleShow ? (
<Component initialValue={2} title="second ternary" />
) : null}

In place using a single ternary operator, the modified code uses two ternary operators.
Please take note that this modified JSX will result in two nodes in the Render Tree always. However, the previous JSX with a single ternary operator had resulted in only one node always. This is the fundamental difference between the codes.
Now we will take a close look at the two nodes created in the new JSX.
Let us start, when the state toggleShow is false.
The Render Tree
// App
//    Component
//    False

Similarly when toggleShow is true.
The Render Tree

// App
//    False
//    Component

The point
The point is this : the structure of the Tree remains the same in all cases. React considers false as a “hole” in the JSX tree, just like null or undefined, and doesn’t render anything in its place. However, the false takes its position.
Therefore, when toggleShow is false
The record of States identified with its components
// someState with value 1 belongs to the first child component in the 
// container

// someState with value 2 belongs to the second child component in the 
// container, since it is a hole and it does not have component to 
// make use of this state, this state will be discarded.

And, when toggleShow is true
The record of States identified with its components
// someState with value 1 belongs to the first child component in the 
// container, since it is a hole and it does not have component to 
// make use of this state, this state will be discarded.

// someState with value 2 belongs to the second child component in the 
// container

What is essentially benefited by the modified code is that we have got the desired result. This demonstrates the first option when it is applied.
We shall see the next option in the next post. Please see the post Retaining state with named components.

React tracks hooks in a specific order during each render of a component using a linked list of hooks tied to the component.
Conditional rendering of components does not interfere with state because each component's state is tracked independently via its node.
When a component is unmounted, React removes the component (and its associated state) entirely from its memory, and remounting creates a new component instance with fresh state.

React maintains the order of useState calls during the rendering of each component, instead of storing a global order.
Rendering process
In the example of the question, the rendering process is something like this:
// Step 1
<App/>

// Step 2
// found one useState call
// storing the state value: true
<div>
  <CounterGroup visible={true}/> // visible is true
  <p> ... </p>
</div>

// Step 3
<div>
  <div>
    <Counter/>
    <Counter/>
  </div>
  <p> ... </p>
</div>

// Step 4
// found one `useState` use in each <Counter/>
<div>
  <div>
    <button> ... </button>
    <button> ... </button>
  </div>
  <p> ... </p>
</div>

Now you can click on the buttons a few times and then click the toggle button.  When visible is set to false, the key difference is at step 3. You may think the re-rendered result is:
// Step 3
<div>
  <div>
    <Counter/>
  </div>
  <p> ... </p>
</div>

If so, React won't know which <Counter/> is left. However, JSX grammar { ... } actually always provides something. When visible is false, the result of the JSX expression is false, instead of nothing. So the resulting tree is actually:
// Step 3
<div>
  <div>
    { false }
    <button> ... </button>
  </div>
  <p> ... </p>
</div>

Therefore, the number of children does not change.
DOM Difference
Since React stores states for each component, it needs to compare the DOM tree  resulted from two renderings, and determine the correspondence between components.
In the example above, there are two different DOM trees in step 3. To be simple, only the different part is written:
// Before
<Counter/>
<Counter/>

// After
{ false }
<Counter/>

By default, React makes components with the same position correspond. That is, the first counter corresponds to { false }, and the second one corresponds to <Counter/>:
<Counter/> => { false }
<Counter/> => <Counter/>

Since { false } has different type from <Counter/>, this correspondence does not make sense, so being ignored. The second correspondence does make sense, so React fill in the states of <Counter/> during the re-rendering process with those of the second counter.
React Key
React key is something that you can tell React how to correspond the children. By setting the key of a component, React will correspond the components with the same key instead of comparing the position index.
When you are using .map to create a number of children, React recommends you to use key property, since using position index to identify components is usually not the expected behavior.
Another example
If you do not use JSX grammar, but use if-else blocks instead, you will get something different:
const CounterGroup = ({ visible }) => {
  // visible controls whether the first counter is displayed
  if (visible) {
    return (
        <div>
          <Counter/>
          <Counter/>
        </div>
    );
  } else {
    return (
        <div>
          <Counter/>
        </div>
    );
  }
};

This time, there is no { false } component being rendered. So the DOM diff will be:
<Counter/> => <Counter/>
<Counter/> => // Nothing here

So the states of the first counter will be applied during re-rendering.

To see there are really two children even if visible is false, you can change the definition of CounterGroup. Instead of directly return the JSX element, you can first assign to a variable result, console.log the variable and then return it. Then you will find the .props.children actually contains two elements, with first being false.

The following post has reference to the first part of the 4-part answer.
Answer part 2 of 4
Conditional rendering:
Let us resume our discussion based on the following two sample codes.
first code
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [toggleShow, setToggleShow] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      {!toggleShow ? (
        <Component initialValue={1} title="true part" />
      ) : (
        <Component initialValue={2} title="false part" />
      )}
      <br />
      <button onClick={() => setToggleShow(!toggleShow)}>
        Click to re-render
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

function Component({ initialValue, title }) {
  const [someState, setSomeState] = useState(initialValue);

  return `I am the Component in the ${title} of the ternary operator with the state someState and the value ${someState}`;
}

Test runs:
Browser display on its first render / loading the App

Browser display on the second render / on the first click of the button

second code
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [toggleShow, setToggleShow] = useState(true);

  return (
    <div>
      {!toggleShow ? (
        <Component initialValue={1} title="true part" />
      ) : (
        <Component initialValue={2} title="false part" />
      )}
      <br />
      <button onClick={() => setToggleShow(!toggleShow)}>
        Click to re-render
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

function Component({ initialValue, title }) {
  const [someState, setSomeState] = useState(initialValue);

  return `I am the Component in the ${title} of the ternary operator with the state someState and the value ${someState}`;
}

Test runs:
Browser display on its first render / loading the App

Browser display on the second render / on the first click of the button

Observations:
While triggering state changes by clicking the button “Click to re-render”, it appears to us as the components re-render on every click, still the states remain the same.
// The first code always shows the state value 1.
    
// The second code always shows the state value 2.

However, what is expected is the below behaviour.
// The first code should show the state values in the order 
// 1,2,1,2,1,2... on load and on each button click respectively.
    
// The second code should show the state values in the order 
// 2,1,2,1,2,1... on load and on each button click respectively.

When we go through the two codes, we can see that the two codes mainly differ only in the initial value set to the state toggleShow. It is as below.
first code
  // ...
  const [toggleShow, setToggleShow] = useState(false);
  // ...

second code
  // ...
  const [toggleShow, setToggleShow] = useState(true);
  // ...

Discussing State retention
With this background, we shall now go into the state retention part.
We shall take the first code first.
Please recall that the first code has toggleState false as its initial value.
The state vs components record in the first render.
// someState with value 1 is assigned to the only one child component of 
// the JSX container. 

Note : From the code and the display, we know that the only one child in the JSX is with respect to the true part of the ternary operator. The same component in the false part is not included in the first render.
Now take the second render or the reaction to the first button click.
The second render will not change the Render Tree, its structure and the component remain the same. There is still only one child in the container. Therefore intuitively we can think the below record has been generated.
The state vs components record in the second render.
// someState with value 2 is assigned to the only one child component of 
// the JSX container. 

However, the law of state retention states that the state in a previous render will retain if the current Render tree has the same component in the same position.
Therefore the state in the previous render, someState with value 1 will be assigned to the only one child component in the current render. Therefore it will result in the latest record as below.
// someState with value 1 is assigned to the only one child component of 
// the JSX container. 

This is the reason we always get the state value 1 even if the component declaration rendered is different in every state change.
Now we shall take the second code.
Please recall that the second code has toggleState true as its initial value.
Therefore the opposite of the points we have discussed so for the first code will happen.
This is the reason we always get the state value 2.
The underlying principle of state retention works in every case - The same component in the same position retains the state.
Now we have discussed the basis on which the React system retains the state. React also provides us ways to control this default behaviour if this default behaviour does not match with our requirement.
However the state retention rule remains unchanged. Keeping the same rule, we can control this default behaviour and meet our needs.
We shall discuss it in the next post. Please refer to the post titled Controlling conditional rendering

Hi, I shall post the third part tomorrow. Please bear with me.

The following post has reference to the first 3 parts of the 4-part answer.
Answer part 4 of 4 - the last part
Retaining state with named components:
Now in this last part of the answer, we shall opt for name based addressing mechanism which will prevail over the default position based addressing.
Let us see the following code, which is a modified version of the first code in part 2nd.
first code modified
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [toggleShow, setToggleShow] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      {!toggleShow ? (
        <Component initialValue={1} title="true part" key="first declaration" />
      ) : (
        <Component initialValue={2} title="false part" key="second declaration" />
      )}
      <br />
      <button onClick={() => setToggleShow(!toggleShow)}>
        Click to re-render
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

function Component({ initialValue, title }) {
  const [someState, setSomeState] = useState(initialValue);

  return `I am the Component in the ${title} of the ternary operator with the state someState and the value ${someState}`;
}

Test runs
Browser display on its first render / loading the App

Browser display on the second render / on the first click of the button

Observations:
The screenshots above show that the modified code has resulted in the expected results.
We shall now see the modification is detail below.
{!toggleShow ? (
<Component initialValue={1} title="true part" key="first declaration" />
              ) : (
<Component initialValue={2} title="false part" key="second declaration" />)}

There is only one ternary operator has been used in the code.
Both component declarations have opted to override the default node addressing mechanism by specifying keys.
Please take note that this code will result in only one node in the Render Tree always. It is unlike the code using the first option which always returns two nodes. This is the first fundamental difference between these two options. The second and the most significant difference is that the two declarations in this code do not use React’s default node addressing mechanism. As we know it is based on the relative position of the nodes in the container.  We override this default scheme by using the props key assigned in the component declarations. Surely we would have have encountered this props key earlier, while rendering an array of JSX. React will warn if a key has not been given for each item of JSX in an array.
Now we will take a close look at the node created in the new JSX.
when the state toggleShow is false.
The Render Tree
// App
//    Component

Similarly when toggleShow is true.
The Render Tree
// App
//    Component

As we have already noted, the structure of the Tree remains the same for both rendering. There is only one single node in the tree.
Therefore, when toggleShow is false
The record of States identified with its components
// someState with value 1 belongs to the component with the key “first 
// declaration”.

And, when toggleShow is true
The record of States identified with its components
// someState with value 2 belongs to the component with the key “second 
// declaration”.

Let us see how the law of state retention applies here.
The law of state retention now applies as the state will retain only those components matched by its key in the two Render trees - the current and the previous one. Therefore in the second render, the law will lead to discarding the state someState with value 1 since it has not found its matching component in the new Tree, as a result state someState with value 2 will retain.
Like in the first option, we have now got the desired result. React describes this option as more generic than the first option.

What you are trying to achieve can be done with moving your child state to parent, So your view part is only dependent on your visible state.
import { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
 const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setVisible(!visible)}>Toggle</button>
      {visible && <Child count={count} setCount={setCount}/>}
    </div>
  )
}

function Child({count,setCount}) {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Click</button>
      <p>{count}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;

